# Mongoose Schema for Groups (a number of users in one group)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

One aspect of my website is that people can join groups according to a specific code provided to them, for example- when we play 'Kahoot' or 'Psych', we have to give a specific code to join the game, here, I am using the same logic to join the user to a group. For people who don't know what I am talking about: I will generate a 3 word code, say, 'absent agitated alive', the user will enter the same thing in the 'Join Group' section and then he can enter the Group.

I want to know how to make the Schema for the different groups and also how to relate groups with users.

This is my current User Schema:

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose')
const UserSchema=new mongoose.Schema({

googleId:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
    
},

displayName:{
    type:String,
    required:true,

},

firstName:{
    type:String,
    required:true,

},

lastName:{
    type:String,
    required:true,

},

image:{
    type:String
    

},

createdAt:{
    type:Date,
    default:Date.now
}})module.exports=mongoose.model('User',UserSchema)
```

I want to know how to make the Groups Schema.
This is my Groups Schema as of now:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const GroupsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

title: {
type: String,
required: true,
},

grp_code: {
type: String,
required: true,
},

users: {
type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: "User",
},

createdAt: {
type: Date,
default: Date.now,
},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Group", GroupsSchema);
```

I want to make the 'users' document in the groups database to be an array, storing the id of all the users who have joined the group. I can't figure out what to do, please help

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use:

```
users: [{
type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: "User",
}],
```

To define an array of users